# overflow: hidden not working on an inner element?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the below example the `overflow: hidden` of the inner element has no effect ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gx9nyv2h/)). The parent elements of the canvas do grow with it and a scrollbar becomes visible. But when I move `overflow: hidden` to the outer element the inner element behaves like it has the `overflow: hidden` style by retaining the size of the outer element without showing scrollbars ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/f6oLs3s0/)). Why does the `overflow: hidden` work on the outer but not on the inner?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.outer {
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.canvas {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set `min-width: 0` on `.outer` for `overflow: hidden` to work on `.inner`. https://jsfiddle.net/gx9nyv2h/5/